# File reading in buffer identical methods between C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, jansson

I was using the [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) C library to parse some JSON file and using the method used in the sample file I tried to parse it using C-like code:

```
FILE *f = fopen(json_path.c_str(), "r");
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);
char* data = (char*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
long rd = fread((void*)data, 1, size, f);
json_t* root = load_json(data);
```

While this code works well if compiled with `gcc`, it doesn't if it is compiled by `g++` as it was the case for me as it was implemented in a C++ class. The errors returned by the Jansson library was about end of file characters.

At that point I tried implementing a more elegant C++-like code to do that:

```
std::ifstream f(json_path.c_str());
if (f) {
  std::stringstream s;
  s << f.rdbuf();
  f.close();
  json_t* root = load_json(s.str().c_str());
}
```

And that code never fails while it seems to me both should do quite the same.

Did I make a mistake in my C-like code in order to read the file in a whole buffer ? How the C++ compilation interpret the C-like code so end of files characters can "disappear" ?

Comment: Is `load_json` perhaps expecting a ***null terminated** character string*? Because the C code does not terminate the data it reads. Is that the problem you have? Is that what you mean by "about end of file characters"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a terminator for the C code. It's just dumb luck that you get away with it in some cases and other times not:

```
char* data = malloc(size + 1);
long rd = fread(data, 1, size, f);
data[size] = '\0';
```

Note that in the C++ version `c_str()` kindly provides a C string terminator for you.

Comment: Was it that simple ? I already manually add that in some cases but it never crossed my mind here. Thanks !

Comment: "just dumb luck" -> "just bad luck". Succeeding due to UB is *worse* than failing